# How to efficiently use blur effect ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, blur, processing-efficiency

I’m currently working on an iOS App. As for usual, on the first launch we have a tutorial. The `ViewController` that is shown after the tutorial (either you skip it or not) is login screen view controller. The background of this VC is a blurred image. And to get the blur effect I’m using `UIImage+ImageEffects.h`.

It seems to take quite a long time (about 5 seconds) to load my VC. But if I comment the line with the blur effect that works like a charm. Do I have anyway of working around this problem? Of course, since the image is static, I have considered using an already blurred image. But on other places in my app I’m gonna use blur effects too. So, I'd like to know if there is a more efficient alternative.

I have seen the question related:

[iOS: How to efficiently blur an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710332/ios-how-to-efficiently-blur-an-image)
but it didn't help me.

Comment: `UIImage+ImageEffects.h` has long been useless since iOS 8 came out with [UIVisualEffectView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial), give that a look!

Comment: If you have to support iOS7, I've been using the `CIGaussianBlur` filter from `CoreImage` which is reasonably fast and you can do it on a background thread so you don't have to block your app while it is processing

Comment: The project referenced by this answer helped me with creating a fast blur in iOS 7 devices: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9601113/1176870

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides [UIVisualEffectView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/) to get the iOS blur effect. I've used a couple of different solutions, including categories on UIImage and GPUImage's iOS7BlurFilter but I've gotten best results with UIVisualEffectView.

Comment: Wouldn't the app crash if I try and run it on iOS 7?
Thanks for the ansswer

Answer (score 0):

I had shared the code for blur effect, you refer the same. [How To Add Visual Effect Views Blur On All Views Storyboard iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625944/how-to-add-visual-effect-views-blur-on-all-views-storyboard-ios/34674005#34674005)

It is working on iOS 7 and above.